# Skype incoming call problem

Tags: skype

When I receive a video call from my contact and press the button to except there call, the skype dies. It end by itself. But when I call to my contact, it works fine.

Also after 40 to 50 min, the Skype ends by itself.
Please help me, as I recently moved to Ubuntu from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, it crashed when I answered. You are probably missing a library. This is required, yet only if you run 64-bit Skype you would have to install it manually. Install by doing the following:

Open a Terminal emulator and enter the following command and hit enter.

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins:i386
```

Enter your password and let it install. After this you should be able to receive calls in Skype.